# About installing LyX!

Tags: lyx, installing

I am trying to install LyX, which is a typewriter program for LaTeX, but I'm having trouble doing it.

Really I tried tons of way to do this, but the error message is the same:

> LyX: No textclass is found
>
> LyX will only have minimal functionality because no textclasses have
>   been found. You can either try to reconfigure LyX normally, try to
>   reconfigure without checking your LaTeX installation, or continue.
>
> (Press the button) Reconfigure (or) Without LaTeX (or) Continue

Comment: What operating system are you on? That's very important. For example, if you're on Ubuntu all you have to do is "sudo apt-get install lyx" and you're done. On Windows and macOS you have to download the installers manually.

Comment: Thanks for attention.
(To Kurt) I am using TeXLive, and I installed MikTex before LyX.

(To scottkosty) The operating system is Windows 10, I followed instructions that were introduced in Youtube. Can I ask you what "manually" means?

Comment: To reply to comments it is @ whoever (only one person) otherwise they will not get your @ tension so for me it is @KJO You should not have both Tex Live and MiKTeX unless you have the experience to split them just check if you have ONE working before starting LyX (TeX Live Full is more than & MiKTeX Basic is less than you need but installed well will expand as required)

Comment: To check pdfLaTeX is generally working fire up a cmd prompt and enter> pdflatex -version (do use a small v) it should show about 12 lines and the first one usually shows **either** pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) or MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6993 (1.40.20) (MiKTeX 2.9.7000)

Comment: @scottkosty The operating system is Windows 10, I followed instructions that were introduced in Youtube. Can I ask you what "manually" means?

Comment: @JJW it means that you have to download the installer rather than just entering that one command I mentioned. I think I've read that it helps on Windows if you install as Administrator, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: some users have in the past had problems with another python on the path interfering during set-up and found using a `set LyXDir=` has helped others have had problems with a space in the directory path (mine is not in "program files") or mapped drives like\\one\two or had to check that lyx settings are changed as per this lyx guide https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Troubleshooting#TextClassList

Comment: > I followed instructions that were introduced in Youtube.

Comment: @KJO I again deleted TeXStudio and LyX, and rebooted the computer, installed MikTeX 2.9 and LyX, but the same result. Now I doubt if there's anything that I can do... haha...

Comment: Referring to the site https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Troubleshooting#TextClassList, that I caanot find the file 'textclass.lst' anywhere may the cause of the problem, I guess.

Comment: Since you changed configuration to MiKTeX it may help to go back to basics. LyX looks for TeX at start-up & should reconfigure itself to suit so important we know how well set MiKTeX is. From any point on your system get cmd prompt type in> `pdfLaTeX --version` you should get a response of numbers confirming that LyX can do similar. If that step says like not an operable command then LyX wont know how to proceed. Also enter> `Where /r \  pdfLaTeX`   which should confirm how many copies may be conflicting (check that it matches> `Where $path:pdflatex` ) the two should agree on one single copy.

Comment: Just a comment to summarise this thread (fresh question moved to another) This inability to install Lyx with EITHER MiKTeX or TeX Live on Windows was due to a Windows \users\name that was not found acceptable to LyX. At present this seems to be a not infrequent issue that is more common to LyX but also plagues both MiKTeX and TeX Live on windows. The other thread is how to work around such limitations by using portable TeX installations https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483668/installing-lyx-no-textclass-is-found